# Check overall UIColor?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, uicolor

Is there a simple way to check the *overall* color of a UIImage?

```
//For example
if ([someImage isMostly:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]] {
    NSLog(@"This image is mostly white!");
}
```

I would imagine it's not that simple though. One approach could be possibly to pick a few random coordinates and average the colors together. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Grab every pixel in the image and average the Reds, the Greens, and the Blues... Then display the averaged color to the user... If you want have a color name I'd assume you could create and array of standard color names and their respective RGB values then use a comparison algorithm to see what matches all 3 values the closest, wouldn't be that hard to make one yourself ;)

Comment: ^Actually... I like the answer below (by @zoul) more... the most frequent color is a much better option... averaging will tell you what the color is if the whole image was viewed from far away or blurred together and viewed close up... but if I have an image that is 75% red and 25% blue the user doesn't want to know that the average color is a purple-red color... they want to know that the image is MOSTLY red.

Comment: Do you want the _mean_ color or the _mode_ of the colors?

Comment: I would be looking for the mean. @JoshCaswell

Comment: @vectorquake Are you sure you don't want the _mode_? ... for example in this image (link at end of comment) the _mean_ would say "The image is mostly pink" where-as the _mode_ would say "The image is mostly white" ... Link: http://us.cdn2.123rf.com/168nwm/itrace/itrace1207/itrace120700367/14640436-business-graph-of-white-bars-and-red-bar-growth-and-reduced-productivity.jpg

Comment: Yeah cause I wouldn't want the image blending together as you mentioned before either. @AlbertRenshaw

Comment: @vectorquake the _mean_ **would** blend the image together... the _mode_ would not.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to create the [image histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_histogram) and then simply pick the most frequent color.